# the screen goes black after onCreate() is called

Tags: android

The screen of my emulator and phone goes black after the onCreate() Method is called and the code after it wont start. It doesn't throw any error it just stalls at the last line of the OnCcreate Method. I think it stops in the Actvity.java file.
log cat

```
02-10 14:00:08.660    2794-2794/com.flashcards.flashcards D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7ff02f1974a0, tid 2794
02-10 14:00:08.670    2794-2794/com.flashcards.flashcards D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
02-10 14:00:08.710    2794-2813/com.flashcards.flashcards D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7ff02f197de0, tid 2813
02-10 14:00:08.740    2794-2813/com.flashcards.flashcards I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-10 14:00:08.780    2794-2813/com.flashcards.flashcards D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
02-10 14:00:08.800    2794-2813/com.flashcards.flashcards W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-10 14:00:08.800    2794-2813/com.flashcards.flashcards W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ff0398bed00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-10 14:00:10.030    2794-2813/com.flashcards.flashcards W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-10 14:00:10.030    2794-2813/com.flashcards.flashcards W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7ff02e6fa940, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-10 14:00:10.260    2794-2813/com.flashcards.flashcards D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7ff036d8dc00 (RippleDrawable) with handle     0x7ff02f1c15c0
```

The method in question

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_question);
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("correct2.txt");
        //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String strLine = null;
        int x = 0;


        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            arrayCorrect[x] = strLine;
            x++;

        }
        if(x>0&&arrayCorrect[x-1]!=null) {
            if (arrayCorrect[x - 1].equals("null") || arrayCorrect[x - 1].equals("")) {
                errorInTranscription();
            }
        }


        //Log.i("File Reading stuff", "success = " + "hell");

    } catch (IOException ioe) {//ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("incorrect2.txt");
        //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String strLine = null;
        int x = 0;


        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            arrayIncorrect[x] = strLine;
            x++;

        }
        if(x>0&&arrayIncorrect[x-1]!=null) {
        if(arrayIncorrect[x].equals("null")||arrayIncorrect[x].equals("")){
            errorInTranscription();
        }}




    } catch (IOException ioe) {//ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    int a=1;
}
```

It gets to the end (int a=1) but it just stalls at the last parathesis

Comment: Do you need to close your streams in `finally` blocks?

Comment: Move the read file to a thread will be a solution!

Comment: It works now that i've closed my streams thank you